# SQL query for finding unique columns & concatenating the results of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a **table A** which contains the following information.

```
+----+-------+-------+-----+--------+-----------+
| ID | jobID | user  | ip  |  time  | userAgent |
+----+-------+-------+-----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | uuid1 | user1 | IP1 | Epoch1 | JSONB1    |
|  2 | uuid1 | user1 | IP2 | Epoch2 | JSONB2    |
|  3 | uuid2 | user3 | IP3 | Epoch3 | JSONB3    |
|  4 | uuid1 | user2 | IP4 | Epoch2 | JSONB2    |
|  5 | uuid1 | user4 | IP5 | Epoch4 | JSONB4    |
|  6 | uuid1 | user1 | IP2 | Epoch2 | JSONB2    |
+----+-------+-------+-----+--------+-----------+
```

**I only want the unique occurrences of (jobID & user) and concatenate the results of users in the following manner.**

> ```
> +-------+-------------------+-------------+
> | jobID |       user        | count(user) |
> +-------+-------------------+-------------+
> | uuid1 | user1,user2,user4 |           3 |
> | uuid2 | user3             |           1 |
> +-------+-------------------+-------------+
> ```

Right now I have written a query like

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT 
  "jobID",
  "user"
 FROM
  "A"
 ORDER BY
  "jobID",
  "user";
```

and it gives me

```
+-------+-------+
| jobID | user  |
+-------+-------+
| uuid1 | user1 |
| uuid1 | user1 |
| uuid2 | user3 |
| uuid1 | user2 |
| uuid1 | user4 |
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group the data by `"jobID"` and use aggregate functions with `distinct`:

```
select 
    "jobID", 
    string_agg(distinct "user", ',') as users, 
    count(distinct "user")
from "A"
group by "jobID"
order by "jobID";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT jobid, string_agg(user, ','), count(*) as num_users
FROM A
GROUP BY jobid;
```

If you don't want duplicates, you can add `distinct`:

```
SELECT jobid, string_agg(distinct user, ','), count(distinct user) as num_users
FROM A
GROUP BY jobid;
```

Comment: This is having issues if the user is duplicate/repeating then the count will be wrong. @klin seems to consider that edge case.

Answer (score 0):

This will surely give you desired output.

```
select "jobID" , string_agg(distinct "user", ',') as users, count as 
"usercount" from 
(select "jobID","user", count("user") as count
from "A"
group by "jobID","user")A 
group by "jobID", count ;
```

Comment: Seems like you have made a typo on line 4, terminating with A. Still the query is wrong ```ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"```

Comment: forgot to fix the typo :)